# Global control in Template10

Tags: uwp, template10

I want to add control in my app like Groove Music's control that can be controlled in every pages. Something like this.

[image: ex. Groove Music]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like a popup like that could be put in the Hamburger within the shell.xaml, then using accessing with a static, similar implementation of the Hamburger would probably be the direction I would go.  I can't say exactly the flow but it would probably be close to what I have stated.

The popup would be up when certain conditions were present